# ScrollViewer thumb is not moving

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, scrollviewer

I have a `TreeView` control, and its template is set like this:

```
<TreeView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="1">
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" 
                          Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualHeight}">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</TreeView.Template>
```

The `TreeView` is filled dynamically:

[image: TreeView filling (gif)]

There are two levels of the `TreeViewItem` nodes:

[image: TreeViewItem nodes (gif)]

And the thumb is moving while in sub items are present only items below:

[image: Sub items]

The Thumb moving:

[image: thumb is moving (gif)]

But when I'm trying to add these items below:

[image: Sub items]

...the thumb is not scrolling, but the `ScrollBar` area is active:

[image: thumb is not moving]

The template of elements is completely the same, but they differ only in the textblock and the image.

I'm stuck on this and can't understand what's wrong.

Which property of the `ScrollViewer` may be changing, which leads to this behavior. Here is the link to the full definition of the `TreeView`: [the treeview definition on github](https://github.com/celephais19/shaft-component-generator/blob/master/src/InventorShaftGenerator/InventorShaftGenerator/Views/MainWindow.xaml#L1780).